# Disable clone repository with https in own Azure DevOps Server installation

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to disable the cloning of a repo with https in my own Azure DevOps Server installation, when I want my users to use SSH only?

Thanks for helping. :)

[Clone Repositoy in Azure DevOps Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6iWG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Disable clone repository with https in own Azure DevOps Server installation

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed**. There is no way to disable it at present.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.